# C storing 2 numbers in one byte

Tags: c, binary, bit-shift

```
u_char  ip_vhl;     /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
```

I can't get it right , how is this done ? 
can you give me examples on how to use this byte to store these 2 numbers 
knowing that each one is 4 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip_vhl = (version << 4) | (headerlen & 0xf);
```

Then the byte will look like this:

```
VVVVHHHH
```

To get back the original values:

```
version = ip_vhl >> 4;
headerlen = ip_vhl & 0xf;
```

Answer (score 5):

If each number is 4 bits, you're going to use the 8-most lower bits of the character. In many cases, this will be all the bits there are.

Do it like so:

```
ip_vhl = ((version & 15) << 4) | (length & 15);
```

Assuming `version` is the one you want in the upper bits, and `length` is what you want in the lower-most bits. The `& 15` makes sure each value only is 4 bits. This is mostly needed for the `length` value, to avoid overwriting bits dedicated to the `version` if length is larger than 15. The decimal constant `15` would be written in hex (as `0xf` or `0x0f`) by many people,  it's a matter of style and taste which you find cleaner.

Another way of writing "an integer with the n right-most bits set to 1, and all other set to 0" is `((1 << n) - 1)`, and since here `n = 4` we could use `((1 << 4) - 1)`, which of course evaluates to `15`.

Your code seems to divide `length` down first and store that, if that's what you want to do you should do it before packing it into the single `char`, for clarity:

```
length >>= 2;  /* Convert from bytes to 32-bit words (or whatever). */
ip_vhl = ((version & 15) << 4) | (length & 15);
```

Comment: 0xf instead of 15 would look nicer

Comment: @ThiefMaster: It's a matter of taste, I guess ... It's one character longer. But I'll edit to mention it.

Comment: I find hex cleaner for bitmasks because it's in a very direct correspondence with the bit pattern. Doesn't mean I always use hex, though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Version (a) using bit fields

```
struct entry {
  unsigned char version : 4;
  unsigned char length  : 4;
} ip_vhl;

ip_vhl.version = version;
ip_vhl.length = length;
```

Version (b) arithmetics

```
ip_vhl = (version << 4) | (length & 0xF)
version = ip_vhl >> 4;
length  = ip_vhl & 0xf;
```

Comment: Bit-fields are very implementation-specific according to C99, the standard. Types other than _Bool and int (signed and unsigned) may not be supported. The order of bit-fields is implementation-defined. How much memory they will take is also implementation-specific (can take more than necessary). Same with alignment.

Comment: @Alex Specific usage depends on your needs. Bit fields can be very useful.

Comment: I didn't say they aren't/can't be useful. I simply warned that they may not be the right or portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Here we are trusting that version and length are both < 0xF
unsigned char ip_vhl = (unsigned char)version << 4 | (unsigned char)length;

unsigned char version = ip_vhl >> 4;
unsigned char length = ip_vhl & 0xF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can resort to a structure with bit fields:

```
typedef struct s_ip_vhl 
{
    int version : 4;
    int header_length : 4;
} ip_vhl_type;

ip_vhl_type my_ip_vhl;
my_ip_vhl.version = 4;
my_ip_vhl.header_length = 5;
unsigned char byte = *((byte*)(&my_ip_vhl));
```

Or you can pack the struct with a union with unsigned char to get the entire byte in one go:

```
typedef union u_ip_vhl
{
    typedef struct s_ip_vhl 
    {
        int version : 4;
        int header_length : 4;
    } ip_vhl_type;
    unsigned char byte;
} ip_vhl_union;
```

Comment: See my comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913760/c-storing-2-numbers-in-one-byte/7913806#7913806)